# if condition in power query source section

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm building a PowerBI report.  I need the source of my query to change based on a variable name.

I tried the below under the source section.

```
= If [TestVal] = "Test" then ODB_File_Business_Sort_order_test else ODB_File_Business_Sort_order
```

But I get the below error

[image]

The **ODB_File_Business_Sort_order** is coming from Sharepoint and the **ODB_File_Business_Sort_order_test** is coming from one drive and I'm trying to switch between the files using a variable.

Any help is appreciated

**Update :**

1. TestVal is a blank query created with value as "Test"
2. The ODB_File_Business_Sort_order and the ODB_File_Business_Sort_order_test are other queries which connects to two files (similar data) in two different locations.  Whenever I want to test/debug, I need use the ODB_File_Business_Sort_order_test otherwise I need to connect to the original file

Comment: Where is [TestVal] coming from?  A cell in the spreadsheet? how would your code refer just to the ODB_File_Business_Sort_order file if that was the only file being used? how would your code refer just to the ODB_File_Business_Sort_order_test file if that was the only file being used?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is possible but while checking your code i see true and false case pass value just act as string.It is not pointing any sharepoint list/file or any one drive file . Please load all two source seprately in independent queries and then use following path with whole line in true and false case.

Hope it work then

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, then, you want

```
let Source = if TestQueryName="Test" then QueryAName else QueryBName,
```

I assume that TestQueryName just outputs a single string. Otherwise you might need to use TestQueryName[Column1]{0} to pull in a single cell from a table